# Receive notification when battery 100% charged on iOS device

Tags: iphone, battery, notifications

Is there any way to receive a iOS notification when you are charging your iPhone and the battery charge level gets to 100%?

Or any third party app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

10 apps for full charge alarm :

http://appcrawlr.com/ios-apps/best-apps-full-charge-alarm

Sound an alarm when your iDevice battery has a full charge :

http://www.cultofmac.com/208576/sound-an-alarm-when-your-iphone-battery-has-a-full-charge-ios-tips/

**And the associated google search :**

https://www.google.fr/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=alert+battery+ios+full+charged&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=808WVryqK6m40wXgt7HoBQ